# I'm missing 2 Salarian Medallions in Mass Effect 1 and I already got to Ilos: will I get the chance to find them?

Tags: mass-effect

No spoilers please. Are there any other new planets to explore after Ilos? Because I actually found a 9th medallion today, after loading from an older save. But I'd rather continue playing on Ilos and find Saren & the Conduit.

If your answer is "no", then it means I'll have to load and search again in every solar system I've been during the first 10 hours of play, when I didn't know that you could find secrets in asteroid belts and on the planets.

Outside of the Salarian Medallions quest, I completed the game 100% ::- ), side quests and everything, so I'm trying to get this last one nailed down as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once you set foot on Ilos, there's no going back. You're unable to return to the Normandy, so what you've got is what you've got.

This is why the Romance video (if applicable) plays during the flight to Ilos, which Bioware mimic'd in the sequel with a similar point of no return.

That said, there's *nothing* earned from finding more Salarian medals. It doesn't carry forward to Mass Effect 2, and you don't even get any real acknowledgments that you've completed it. This might be one case where you have to look at your inner perfectionist, and get them to say, "Eh, close enough".

Comment: That's one thing about ME1 I don't like.  My first play-through, I didn't realize that I couldn't go back and finish all the side missions.